# Redis – Nested hashes vs. string values

Tags: caching, redis, stackexchange.redis

I need to cache access rights using Redis.
The access rights are per user (a user of the application), function (something the user can do) and machine (a machine for which the user can perform the function).

For example:
*UserA, edit name, machine1

Or UserB, delete machine, machine40*

The application contains about 1000 functions, 6000 machines and 300 users.
I’m not sure what’s the best idea of storing the access rights.

**Option 1:**
Storing the access rights as single string, like this:

```
redis> set userA_EditName_machine1 true
redis> set userA_EditName_machine2 false
redis> set userB_DeleteMachine_machine40 false
```

**Option 2:**
Storing the access rights as nested hashes:

```
redis> hset users:userA:EditName machine1 true
redis> hset users:userA:EditName machine2 false
redis> hset users:userB:DeleteMachine machine40 false
```

My application is a ASP.Net MVC application and I’m using StackExcahnge.Redis to work with Redis.

Does one option have any advantages over the other?

**Edit:**

The application needs to check if the user is allowed to perform a certain operation on a certain machine.
The query would look like this:

**Option 1:**

```
redis> get user0_function0_machine1
```

**Option 2:**

```
redis> hget users:user0:function0 machine1
```

Comment: Please specify what queries you need to perform - that will determine the optimal data storage manner.

Comment: @ItamarHaber I’ve added the queries to the question

Comment: Recommended lecture: [Assessment of
Access Control Systems](http://csrc.nist.gov/publications/nistir/7316/NISTIR-7316.pdf)

Comment: @thepirat000 Thanks for the link. I will take a look at it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should consider storing the *Access Control List* (a list of permissions attached to a user-machine) as a redis hash.

This way you can query the entire collection of permissions for a subject or just query for a particular object permission.

For example, you have the following users (Subjects):

- john:machine1
- john:machine2
- mary:machine1

The following features (or Objects):

- editname
- deletemachine

And the following Permissions:

- Y (access granted)
- N (access denied)

You can have one hash for each subject with **key -> field -> value** as follows:

```
ACL:{username}:{machine} -> {object} -> {permission}
```

So you can query for a particular object permission like this:

```
redis> HGET ACL:john:machine2 editname
"Y"
```

Or query the entire the collection of permissions for a subject:

```
redis> HGETALL ACL:john:machine2
1) "editname"
2) "Y"
3) "deletemachine"
4) "N"
```

Of course you can choose to store only the granted permissions, and assume a denied permission by default.